# Spotless + Java Google format vs Intellij + import file

Tags: java, maven, google-java-format, spotless

I am trying to configure a maven spring boot application to use spotless with google java format style. I would like as well to have Intellij formatting the code as the maven plugin does.

But i am noticing that the formmat applied differ a little bit.

One example:
Intellij will not change the following 2 lines

```
@Mock 
private UserRepository userRepositoryMock;
```

But the maven plugin (using the command: mvn spotless:apply) will format like this:

```
@Mock private UserRepository userRepositoryMock;
```

**POM CONFIG**

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>com.diffplug.spotless</groupId>
                <artifactId>spotless-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${spotless.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <!-- optional: limit format enforcement to just the files changed by this feature branch -->
                    <ratchetFrom>origin/master</ratchetFrom>
                    <formats>
                        <!-- you can define as many formats as you want, each is independent -->
                        <format>
                            <!-- define the files to apply to -->
                            <includes>
                                <include>*.md</include>
                                <include>.gitignore</include>
                            </includes>
                            <!-- define the steps to apply to those files -->
                            <trimTrailingWhitespace/>
                            <endWithNewline/>
                            <indent>
                                <spaces>true</spaces>
                                <spacesPerTab>4</spacesPerTab>
                            </indent>
                        </format>
                    </formats>
                    <!-- define a language-specific format -->
                    <java>
                        <!-- no need to specify files, inferred automatically, but you can if you want -->
                        <importOrder>  <!-- or a custom ordering -->
                            <order>java,javax,org,com,microservices.book.multiplication,
                            </order>  <!-- or use <file>${project.basedir}/eclipse.importorder</file> -->
                            <!-- you can use an empty string for all the imports you didn't specify explicitly, and '\\#` prefix for static imports -->
                        </importOrder>

                        <removeUnusedImports/> <!-- self-explanatory -->

                        <!-- apply a specific flavor of google-java-format and reflow long strings -->

                        <googleJavaFormat>
                            <version>1.14.0</version>
                            <style>GOOGLE</style>
                            <reflowLongStrings>true</reflowLongStrings>
                        </googleJavaFormat>
                        <indent>
                            <tabs>true</tabs>
                            <spacesPerTab>2</spacesPerTab>
                        </indent>
                        <indent>
                            <spaces>true</spaces>
                            <spacesPerTab>4</spacesPerTab>
                        </indent>
                    </java>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

**On Intellij**
I added the the following code stile from google

**Github site**
https://github.com/google/google-java-format

**IntelliJ Java Google Style file**
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/google/styleguide/gh-pages/intellij-java-google-style.xml

[image: Intellij code style window]

Why the differences? What else may differ? How can I have Intellij formatting the code exactly as the google java code style format xml file?

Thank you so much for your help in advance

Regards

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? Running into the same issue right now.

Comment: we decided to use spotless + google format only (while a small change using 4 spaces indentation instead of 2). On the top of this we created a git hook (pre-commit) which always apply the format before the commit to all the modified files, stage them and them commits. Applying the format is completely transparent :)

Answer (score 0):

From documentation to fix the annotations problems:

```
<!-- fixes formatting of type annotations, see below -->
<formatAnnotations />
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).